# Firebase Web is only saving a single branch, not both

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to save data in firebase with node.js.

Here is my code:

```
function writeDataToFirebase(candidate, score) {
    var id = guid();

    var date = new Date();
    var milli = date.getTime();
    var milliPutToString = milli.toString();

    db.ref('tweets/'+candidate+'/'+ id).set({
        sentimentScore: score,
        date: milliPutToString
    });
}
```

This is the only function I use to push data, and yet, here is the json that it generates:

```
{
  "tweets" : {
    "clinton" : {
      "2a3e99bd-fd57-6893-a3e5-1c5a92ed0d7e" : {
        "sentimentScore" : 0.5684505
      }
    },
    "trump" : {
      "1d2692ee-3b6e-25ee-cbbc-8c9b6e2b2dd4" : {
        "sentimentScore" : 0.6392453
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Where's your code to pull that JSON? I see a `set` but where's the observer that's spitting out the snapshot value?

Comment: @ceejayoz I don't use one. I am only writing to the database from the web, and am reading from an iOS app.

Comment: @charlietfl there should be a branch under "sentimentScore"  with the current date in milliseconds too

Comment: Is the code in your question identical to the code in your app? The code in the question looks okay, but if the value of `date` in the object literal passed to `set` happened to be `undefined` the behaviour would be explained.

Comment: Yes it is exactly the same. I'm pretty flustered... probably going to give up for the night. @cartant

Comment: The code looks fine at first sight. Can you set up a repro on jsbin? Or on [tonicdev](https://tonicdev.com/npm/firebase) if it's node-specific?